# Q number format

Tags: solidity, uniswap

The fees in the uniswap contracts are in Q128.128 format. But the docs don't mention if this is signed or unsigned. Does anyone know ?

If it's unsigned, then simply dividing by 2^128 should give the decimal value, but there are  instances where the fee value is so large that the resultant decimal value is of the order 10^38, which seems incorrect for feeGrowth.

Example large value for feeGrowth `115792089237316195423570985008687907853257841863697467297596591912899715160488`

Comment: the  (official Uniswap) docs say `feeGrowthGlobal0X128` and `feeGrowthGlobal1X128` can overflow